# Woocommerce filter products on admin grid by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added manufacture column in product admin grid in woocommerce. Now i want to search product by manufacturer also. I have added manufacture_id in post_meta for products.

I have to search manufacture first by search term and if any manufacture exist then search for manufacture id in product post_meta field. It may also return multiple manufactures.

I am using following filter:

```
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'ls_product_posts_filter' );

function ls_product_posts_filter( $query ){
    global $pagenow;

    $type = 'product';
    if (isset($_GET['post_type'])) {
        $type = $_GET['post_type'];
    }
    if ( 'product' == $type && is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php') {
        $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'manufacture_id';
    }
}
```

Thanks.